# How to accept user input of a sequence?

Tags: python, while-loop, numbers

I'm new to python and I'm trying to help out a friend with her code. The code receives input from a user until the input is 0, using a while loop. I'm not used to the python syntax, so I'm a little confused as to how to receive user input. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
sum = 0
number = input()
while number != 0:
   number = input()
   sum += number
   if number == 0:
     break
```

Comment: Inputs from `input()` come in as a string. You need to convert it to a number (e.g. `int(number)`). Though you will have to be careful as this could fail if they actually pass in a letter

Comment: Ok, so the new problem is that `input` always returns a string so you need to convert it to `int`/`float`. Please test the code and ensure it's an accurate representation before posting.

Comment: You don't need the last 2 lines. The `while` will test true when zero is entered for number.

Comment: Yes, please read the comments

Answer (score 0):

No need last `if`, and also make inputs `int` typed:

```
sum = 0
number = int(input())
while number != 0:
   number = int(input())
   sum += number
```

You can actually do:

```
number=1
while number!=0:
   number = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, both `while number != 0:` and `if number == 0: break` are controlling when to exit the loop. To avoid repeating yourself, you can just replace the first condition with `while True` and only keep the `break`.

Also, you're adding, so it is a good idea to turn the read input (which is a character string) into a number with something like `int(input())`.

Finally, using a variable name like `sum` is a bad idea, since this 'shadows' the built-in name `sum`.

Taking all that together, here's an alternative:

```
total = 0
while True:
    number = int(input())
    total += number
    if number == 0:
        break
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Declare list for all inputs
input_list = []

# start the loop
while True:

    # prompt user input
    user_input = int(input("Input an element: "))
    # print user input
    print("Your current input is: ", user_input)

    # if user input not equal to 0
    if user_input != 0: 
        # append user input into the list
        input_list.append(user_input)

    # else stop the loop    
    else:
        break

    # sum up all the inputs in the list and print the result out
    input_sum = sum(input_list)
    print ("The sum is: ", input_sum)
```

## Or

If you don't want to use `list`.

```
input_list = 0
while True:
    user_input = int(input("Input an element: "))
    print("Your current input is: ", user_input)

    if user_input != 0: 
        input_list += user_input

    else:
        break

    print ("The sum is: ", input_list)
```

## Note:

```
raw_input('Text here')       # Python 2.x
input('Text here')           # Python 3.x
```